# How to send boolean parameter using curl, http?

Tags: jenkins, parameters, boolean

I am trying to send boolean parameter using curl, http-get to Jenkins without success. Need someone to tell me what is wrong here.

I did try to send it as `true` , `True` and `1` but none of this works.

Job in jenkins is set as pipeline and is parametrized. There are 3 parameters added from GUI:

- bp1 boolean 1
- bp2 boolean 2
- sp string (this one is to check if parameters are send at all

Default values are as below:

- bp1 - false
- bp2 - false
- sp - null

Pipeline code:

```
stage ('bools') {
    echo 'bool 1 is:' + params.bp1
    echo 'bool 2 is:' + params.bp2
    echo 'string is:' + params.sp
}
```

Command used to invoke build (in browser or postman):

`http://X.X.X.X/jenkins/job/bool_debug/buildWithParameters?token=booltest&bp1=true&bp2=false$sp='this is text from param'`

Expected result is `bool 1 is:true` but got `bool 1 is:false`. Jenkins did not change (tick checkbox) boolean parameter when invoking from API. In other means:

What I get:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (bools)
[Pipeline] echo
bool 1 is:false
[Pipeline] echo
bool 2 is:false
[Pipeline] echo
string is:'this is text from param'
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

What it should be:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (bools)
[Pipeline] echo
bool 1 is:true    <--------------------------
[Pipeline] echo
bool 2 is:false
[Pipeline] echo
string is:'this is text from param'
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same issue, think it's a Jenkins bug. I ended up creating another pipeline which triggers the desired pipeline with params as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

We're working with Jenkins 2.387.1 and using HTTP POST with `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` passing boolean parameters as (string) `true` in the body results in the parameter being enabled properly.

Either HTTP GET was the issue and POST would have helped or this was fixed in the meantime.